# Including many variables inside a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to store inside a dictionary (name) many different variables (int, double, string, etc) that describes one object (name), like this:

```
string ref = "BCB";
int voltage = 12;
double watts = 60;
double width = 12.5;
double height = 15.5;
double cost = 10.2;
```

I have read about dictionaries but i don´t understand how do i have to store this variables inside it.

Can you write an example with this variables?

Comment: this is a duplicate question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105361/how-do-i-create-a-dictionary-that-holds-different-types-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way - make a class out of them.

An ugly but still working way: ValueTuples:

```
Dictionary<string, (string ref, int voltage, double watts, double width, double height, double cost> dict;

dict.Add("Name", ("Ref", 10, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 100.0));
```

Comment: I hope he will not use `ValueTuples`:)

Comment: Why am I getting randomly downvoted on this post? Is something wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that in your intended way (although it is possible as `<string, object>`. Dictionary is by design a `<key, value>` pair. 
What you need to do is either create a struct or a class, which will hold your attributes.

Comment: what about `Dictionary<string, object>` ?

Comment: I assume that could work but isn't that a design flaw? AFAIK, dictionaries should not be used for this purpose.

Comment: Ofcourse, you are right. Dictionaries are primary for holding objects of a same (base) type and this solution is "Bad By Design". But this is a posible way, so you shouldn't say that _"You can't do that in your intended way"_

Comment: Edited my answer to be aware of this fact

Answer (score 0):

you can use string and object type, 
just keep to your attention that if you will need to manage casting logic if you will wish to use your data.

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        int voltage = 12;
        double watts = 60;
        double width = 12.5;
        double cost = 10.2;
        string name = "BCB";
        dic.Add("voltage", watts);
        dic.Add("watts", width);
        dic.Add("height", voltage);
        dic.Add("cost", cost);
        dic.Add("name", name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use 
    Dictionary < string, dynamic >
 in C# 4 / .NET 4 - but other than that, you can't do it with exactly the code shown because there's no type which is implicitly convertible to int, string and double. (You could write your own one, but you'd have to list each type separately.)

You could use Dictionary but then you'd need to cast the results:

```
int a = (int) Storage.Get("age");
string b = (string) Storage.Get("name");
double c = (double) Storage.Get("bmi");
```

Alternatively, you could make the Get method generic:

```
int a = Storage.Get<int>("age");
// etc
```