# How do I create a dictionary type that holds different types in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, functional-programming

I'd like to define a type for dictionaries that holds different types as values. In fact I'm looking for [How do I create a Dictionary that holds different types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105361/how-do-i-create-a-dictionary-that-holds-different-types-in-c-sharp) but for an [immutable dict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary) type instead of for a dict "variable".

Let's say I have a dictionary representing the data of a user

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;

var immutableUserVariable = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Id", 0 },
            { "FirstName", "Annett" },
            { "LastName", "Jones"},
            { "Active", true}
        }.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

The types are implicitly inferred as follows (output of [.NET interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive)):

```
|    key    |      type      |  value |
|:---------:|:--------------:|:------:|
| LastName  | System.String  | Jones  |
| Active    | System.Boolean | True   |
| FirstName | System.String  | Annett |
| Id        | System.Int32   | 0      |
```

I can use this user inside an immutable list like follows

```
var immutableUserList = new[] { immutableUserVariable }.ToImmutableList();
immutableUserList
```

However instead of creating the dictionary variable `immutableUserVariable` I'd like to create a type for this custom, immutable dictionary (`User`) which I can use for creation of variables instead. This would allow me to create lists using the specific dict type with e.g.

```
var immutableListBuilder = ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<User>();
// add dicts of type User
immutableListBuilder.Add(...);
immutableListBuilder.Add(...);
```

Comment: I've nothing yet.

Comment: Alright, can you explain your intended usage and why you need it and why the links you link to don't help? What do you mean by "instead of for a dict "variable""?

Comment: I'd like to define a type for a "User" with specified types for the single fields (Id -> int, FirstName -> string, LastName -> string, Active -> bool) of an immutable dict (not sorted). This type I'd like to use to create and re-create immutable dicts in a functional manner.

Comment: In case someone knows functional programming concepts (immutability) it should be pretty clear what I'm aiming for. I'm not used C# for ages and never used functional style C# yet. The syntax is probably the main limitation for me right now :)

Comment: I agree. I'll improve the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've added code to make clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to use a `Dictionary`? `User` should be a class (which is a type) with fields...

Comment: @NetMage Good point. However I need to provide an example how to use immutable dicts and limmutable ists instead of their mutable couterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object type for value

```
Dictionary<string, object> pairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        
pairs.Add("key1", 1);
pairs.Add("key2", "string");

int i = (int)pairs["key1"];
```

Or you can create custom class:

```
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public T Get<T>(string key)
        => (T)this[key];
}

MyDictionary pairs = new MyDictionary();
pairs.Add("key1", 1);
pairs.Get<int>("key1");
```

Comment: This does have performance impact but it will work as intended as long as you do not have a null struct popping up at some point.